# For a fixed density altitude, how does climb performance depend on pressure altitude?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, performance-calculation, climb, density-altitude

Below is the climb performance from the 1978 Cessna 152 POH, which I've plotted as climb rate versus density altitude. It shows that higher pressure altitude gives decreased performance even when the density altitude is approximately the same. It also gives a different climb speed for each pressure altitude, so it isn't exactly comparing apples to apples. But it identifies this as the best climb speed so it still claims that performance is degraded with higher pressure altitude independently of density altitude.

[image: Climb rate vs density altitude for Cessna 152. Source: Own work based on POH numbers.]

Is this trend accurate? If so, how and why does pressure altitude affect climb performance for a fixed density altitude?

Comment: Because the loss of climb performance at the higher PA overwhelms the gain in performance from the lower temperatures associated with the unchanging density altitude? Guessing, but that seems consistent with your data.

Comment: What type of aircraft does this POH come from?

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni Whoops. It's from a Cessna 152.

Comment: The differences in climb rate for the same density altitude may be due to differences in pitch and airspeed (slower is more Vx like).  Note that increasing density altitude lowers Vy.  You can almost use that chart to determine DA from PA and climb performance!

Comment: @ThomasPerry The x-axis here is density altitude. For instance, at 5000 feet pressure altitude the climb rate varies from a little over 400 to more than 500 at essentially the *same* density altitude as the pressure altitude varies from 2000 feet to 8000 ft. I know that performance is degraded at higher density altitude- I'm asking why it is also degraded at *higher pressure altitude/lower temperature for a fixed density altitude.*

Comment: @Chris Temperature!

Comment: @ThomasPerry How so? Lower temperature gives *worse* performance here for the same density altitude (lower pressure and the same density means lower temperature). If it is because of temperature, the trend would naively go in the other direction.

Comment: @ThomasPerry *How* does temperature affect things? Most of the aerodynamics are, to leading order, dependent only on the density. If it's the engine, why does *colder* temperature lead to decreased performance for a fixed density?

Comment: @ThomasPerry Yes, that follows from the ideal gas law $P=\rho k_B T/\bar{m}$. I used that to compute the density altitude in the first place in order to make this plot. I'm well aware that the temperature is different among these points. I'm less clear what aerodynamic or mechanical difference temperature makes on the performance of the aircraft for a fixed density.

Comment: @Chris  Yes, this is all thermodynamics.  In fact, your question is one of the most interesting I've ever seen on se-aviation...

Comment: @Chris Lycoming gives a cursory estimate of power available at density altitude.  A noted follow up regarding this in KitPlanes was never published. The solution is indeed temperature dependent and is apparently related to indicated horsepower...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it depends on how you read the graph.  If indicated airspeed is held constant, then the graph shows lower climb rate for higher density altitude.

Just stick with one airspeed reading it.

It appears that the listed KIAS is best for that pressure altitude, with the corresponding effect of higher density altitude on climb rate.

This makes sense considering *hotter* air at the same pressure will be thinner (less dense).

The chart depicts decreasing Vy with higher density altitude.

Comment: Yes, it certainly shows decreased performance with higher temperature at fixed pressure altitude, and that makes sense. My question is about why is *also* shows decreased performance with lower temperature (higher pressure altitude) at fixed density altitude.

Comment: @Chris always interesting to think whether "higher" refers to pressure or altitude.  I believe it refers to what the altimeter reads.  So "higher pressure altitude" with the same density altitude would actually mean one is *lower* than the altimeter is reading, because they are in *colder* than Standard air.

Comment: @Chris so I don't think the graph is reflecting the same density altitude for all data points.  It may be: for a given pressure and density at point A, here is your performance when your altimeter is at 2000, 4000, 6000 etc.  Essentially, it is giving  best rate of climb Vy under those conditions.

Comment: Density altitude is the x-axis. The points that are clustered together are at different pressure altitudes and approximately the same density altitude.

Comment: @Chris try holding pressure altitude constant for each point/KIAS, and read the points for variable density altitude (corresponding to your climb rate).  Aviators (even from the 1970s) read pressure altitude, and calculate density altitude based on temperature deviation from Standard.